# Where are Parse servers located?

Tags: parse-platform

I am looking to reduce the latency between my server and Parse.com servers. According to [this page](https://www.parse.com/questions/data-center-location), Parse says:

> Our servers are currently located in the East Coast of the United States.

According to [this page](https://parse.com/about/security), Parse is using Amazon's data center.

Can anyone positively confirm then that Parse.com servers are the Amazon N. Virginia data center?

Also, will being in that same data center be enough to reduce latency or are there any additional decisions I can make to reduce latency even further (like subnet selection, type of instance, etc.)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for the geographic location of a 3rd party's servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic ping to api.parse.com results in this :

```
ping api.parse.com

Pinging parse-api-vpc-2122016640.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com [54.86.133.21] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 54.86.133.21: bytes=32 time=211ms TTL=40
Reply from 54.86.133.21: bytes=32 time=208ms TTL=40
Reply from 54.86.133.21: bytes=32 time=208ms TTL=40

Ping statistics for 54.86.133.21:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 208ms, Maximum = 211ms, Average = 209ms
```

So I think they are situated in us-east-1.